# How to set `contextType` on stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I am using the `React` context new API as below code. The last line will register the context into my component. I wonder how I can use the `contextType` for stateless component?

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value of MyContext */
  }
}
MyClass.contextType = MyContext;
```

I tried below code but it doesn't seem to work. The `context` in the component is empty object.

```
const MyClass = (props, context) => {
...
}
MyClass.contextType = MyContext;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no way of doing it with contextType.
You should use contextConsumer with renderProps pattern or React's useContext hook (introduced in React 16.8)

The first one will look like this:

```
const MyClass = (props) => {
    return (
        <myContext.Consumer>
            {({name}) => <View>{name}</View>}
        </myContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

And the second (preferred) way of doing it looks like this:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

const MyClass = (props) => {
    const {name} = useContext(myContext)
    return <View>{name}</View>
}
```

Comment: Using hook is best practice for a functional component for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You must import `useContext`, then define a variable which fills output of `useContext` with the argument of your defined context.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

const MyClass = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(yourContext)
    return <p>{context.name}</p>
}
```